# apparmor on fedora / rhel / centos

Tags: ubuntu, centos, redhat, fedora, apparmor

My application relies heavily on AppArmor for security. I use Ubuntu to host it myself, but I have gotten requests from others that want to host in on a Fedora or RHEL machine.

Now I am aware that Redhat prefers people to use SElinux instead of AppArmor. However, I have looked into it, and I think it is going to be very hard to translate my AppArmor profiles to SElinux policies.  Furthermore, I don't think it is very linux-like to force software on the user. Ubuntu for example supports both SElinux and AppArmor and leaves it up to the user. I don't see why Redhat wouldn't do the same.

Anyway, most of the stuff on google about rhel + apparmor is pretty outdated. How is the support of AppArmor in the latest versions of RHEL / Fedora? Is it possible to get it working without manually building a kernel? Are there any packages available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're out of luck - it looks like you have to create a custom kernel for RHEL/CentOS and even then it's [experimental](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/Distro_CentOS) (old CentOS 5.5).

Comment: Well this doc describes centos5. AppArmor is now part of the default linux kernel, so I was hoping that it might be easier on RHEL 6 or Fedora. Also, I don't really need all of the AppArmor tools that help with creating profiles. I have the profiles so I just need to get it running.